# Javascript/JQuery remove parent TR issue in code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with many rows and I've added a remove button to every row and created a function where each button removes it's parent TR

Here's the code:

```
//HTML

<tr>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        data 1
    </td>
    <td>
        data 2
    </td>
    <td>
        data 3
    </td>
    <td>
        data 4
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="removeCurrentRow();">remove</a>
    </td>
</tr>


//Javascript

function removeCurrentRow() {

    $(this).parent('tr').hide();

}
```

I've also tried:

```
$(this).closest("tr").hide();
$(this).parent('tr').remove();
$(this).parent('tr').hide();
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
```

But none of them are removing the parent TR

Where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: why not create a common click event instead of all these `onclick`s in your DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass this while calling function:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        1
    </td>
    <td>
        data 1
    </td>
    <td>
        data 2
    </td>
    <td>
        data 3
    </td>
    <td>
        data 4
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="removeCurrentRow(this);">remove</a>
    </td>
</tr>


//Javascript

function removeCurrentRow(obj) {

    $(obj).closest('tr').hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current object as well,

```
 <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="removeCurrentRow(this);">remove</a>
```

then the code will be,

```
function removeCurrentRow(obj) {

    $(obj).closest('tr').hide();

}
```